# Combining (multiplexing) pipes into one (linewise). Is there such program?

Tags: linux

Is there already a program that reads multiple pipes or file descriptors and writes to the standard output (not splitting lines).

Like `cat`, but reading all files simultaneously and preserving lines.

Something like:

```
until(all fds are EOF) {
    select(multiple fds);
    read a line from triggered fd;
    write the line to the stdout;
}
```

It is needed to avoid coding of select/epoll loops or using multithreading in simple programs. Like "select loop for bash".

Update: I've also [created](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102831/how-to-combine-lines-printed-by-multiple-programs-safely) a similar question on unix.SE.

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to accomplish. This almost sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, Every time I want to write a oneliner that shares output the problem arises. Program with even loop is sometimes too big to simple one-shot tasks.

Comment: Please be more specific. Can you post an example?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, I have a stateful program that reads data from /dev/input/whatever and issues HTTP requests and starts other programs. And now I want it to handle multiple input devices (but don't want to think about FD loops or threading). I want solution that can be applied to any of such problems. Like pipe demultiplexor/multiplexor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a program to do just it: fdlinecombine. It reads specified file descriptors and outputs the data linewise.

- Source: https://github.com/vi/fdlinecombine
- Static binary: http://vi-server.org/pub/fdlinecombine_static

Checked some corner cases, tested a bit. Hoping it will be useful for somebody too.

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution could be to use:

```
tail -fq file1 file2 file3 | grep -v ^$ | yourprogram
```

I name this a partial solution because the `grep` removes the empty line that `tail` adds every times it changes file. If your input contains empty lines, they are removed.

Comment: Clever, a +1 from me.

Comment: Fails: mkfifo pipe1 pipe2 && tail -fq pipe1 pipe2; then writing to pipe2 hangs.

Comment: tail -f on multiple pipes works in general bad unless it had read each of them at least once.

Comment: Also it is slow.

Answer (score 1):

A alternative using xargs(1) and tail(1):

Create the data sources:

```
$>touch datafile.txt
$>mkfifo pipe1
$>mkfifo pipe2
```

Start tail processes with xargs:

```
$>echo datafile.txt pipe1 pipe2 | xargs -n 1 -P 0 tail -f >> datasink.txt
```

Push data into sources:

```
$>echo dataset1 > pipe1
$>echo dataset2 > datafile.txt
$>echo dataset3 > pipe1
$>echo dataset4 > pipe2
```

Show data from sink:

```
$>cat datasink.txt 
dataset1
dataset2
dataset3
dataset4
```